# After Web Site Inactivity Ninject failes to load resource

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ninject, iis-8

I have a ASP.Net Web API service (4.5.1) that is using Ninject to resolve components.   When I start the web site in IIS 8 and run it... It works fine.  If I let quite awhile pass before making additional calls, Ninject stops resolving my components and my web service returns null instead of JSON data.

It runs fine for calls separated by as much as 10 minutes,  I have not nailed down when it stops working.

This has to be some sort of configuration thing with Ninject or IIS. Any help would be appreciated.

```
private static IKernel _current = new StandardKernel();  
_current.Bind<IRepositoryFactory>(typeof(MyRepositoryFactory));
```

I have complex wrapper code around the objects. The Kernel is created as shown above. Each class that I need resolved implements an IDependencyRegistrar Interface which is searched for by wrapper code during application startup.   When found, I call a method named Register which runs the second line of code shown above.

Comment: Could you plese post some sample code such as: The container initialization code, your bindings, etc? The issue may be related to IIS recycles.

Comment: Not sure what you need to see.  As I said the code that initializes the container works for some period of time.   However, I can say this, when it stops working, recycling the Site, the App Pool, and IIS do not restore it to working.  I must stop the site and the app pool and then Rebuild the solution in Visual Studio 2013.   After that it works again for  some time.   I have tried delays between calls up to 10 minutes and they work.  A successful call seems to result in it working a longer period of time in other words, if I call it every 5 minutes for 6hours it never fails.

Comment: I need to see the bindings (to resolve any lifetime issues), where the kernel is stored at kernel initialization code, how is the kernel created, etc... if you are using the Nuget packages, basically the `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file.

Comment: I updated the original post with 2 lines of code.  I have fairly complex code that wraps the Kernel and wraps classes that need to be registered in the container.  Basically, I search all loaded assemblies looking for classes the implement IDependencyRegistrar and then call the Register method on each class I find.  Inside the register function you find the second line of code shown in the post.